# iPad video loading issue

Tags: objective-c, ipad, video

I am developing a swipe based application. On each swipe a page will appear containing a video with some other asset. I am using the following code to do this for me on each swipe.

```
    NSArray *file = [videoFile componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."]];
    
    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[file objectAtIndex:0] ofType:[file objectAtIndex:1]];
    
    if (moviePath != nil) 
    {
        //self.videoTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delayTime target:self selector:@selector(playVideo:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        self.theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
        self.theMovie.view.frame = self.bounds;
        self.theMovie.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
        self.theMovie.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
        self.theMovie.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        
        [self addSubview:self.theMovie.view];
        [self.theMovie release];
    }
    else 
    {
        [AssetValidator alertMissingFileInfo:videoFile];
    }
```

This works fine.

My problem is that each time I swipe, video starts with a delay and black screen. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

How big are the movies? If their size is big then it's OK. There is a solution but it's quite irrational - load all the movies to memory during app startup and runtime. Otherwise (if the movies are quite big), the delay will happen anyway.

Comment: Thanks knodel. Approximately 2MB. But number of pages can be 300. Can you please tell how to put videos in memory?

Comment: Wow! Then it is going to be 600 megabytes in the memory - "a bit" too much! I don't think there's any solution then. If the movies are loaded each time, the delay will remain.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a background Image to avoid black screen.